# Binding to localStorage in ionic doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

Im working on an ionic application and im having some trouble binding a scope variable to a local storage var.

*Im using the [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) library.

in my controller I did :

```
$scope.name = $localStorage.name;
```

in html

```
<div data-ng-bind="name"></div>
```

I also have a sevice function that is executed in app.module().run() and initiates the local storage "name" variable from an external server.

I tested the local storage and its value is ok! The problem im having is with the HTML that doesnt get updated in real time when the value of the $localStorage.name changes. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you injected the "ngStorage" dependancy in the module and $localStorage in your controller. Detailed steps were given by Nic Raboy in his [blog](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/12/use-ngstorage-angularjs-local-storage-needs/). Also in your html you can get the name by <div> {{name}}</div>. You can took a look at his blog for elaborated steps.

Comment: @Sabarish I read this blog post today and did everything it says. Setting and getting from the $localstorage works fine. My only problem is that my binding doesnt work. I dont get any errors ...

Comment: Are you watching the localstorage value? or how are you continously setting it?

Comment: data-ng-bind does the same as an expression, i tried the both ways. When i refresh the page the data seems ok but it should change in real time without the refresh.

Comment: Where and how are you updating you're `$scope.name` variable? **ngStorage** needs a digest cycle in order to be updated correctly.
> the new values will not reliably be saved into the browser local storage. Allow a digest cycle to occur by using a zero-value $timeout

Check https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage#watch-the-watch where it's explained.

Comment: For dynamic update, can you try using this method in controller
  $scope. name = function(){
    return $localStorage.name;
  }
and <div data-ng-bind="name()"></div> in your html.

Comment: @Sabarish This actually work! Thanks alot. Post is as an answer

Comment: @Sabarish I forgot to ask you, why does it actually work this way? i dont understand the difference between an assignment ,as i did , and assigning an anonymous function that returns the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamic update, can you try using this method in controller

> $scope. name = function(){ return $localStorage.name; }

and in your html please add the below line

```
<div data-ng-bind="name()"></div>
```